# Counting (Multi)Polygons Within (Multi)Polygons on same Table

Tags: polygon, sql, geometry, spatialite, query

So I have a table with approximately 10k rows, with each row having its corresponding geometry entry. What I am attempting to do is count how many row geometries are contained/within the geometry of a single row as follows:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM poly_table
WHERE WITHIN(poly_table.geom, poly_table.geom)
GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

However, all I get in return is a table with all rows having a `COUNT(*)` value of `1`. So in understand they will certainly contain themselves but there are definitely polygons within polygons that are not accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing **each geometry to itself**, and for `[ST_]Within/[ST_]Contains`, a geometry is a positive match for itself!

You need to *self-join* the table to allow for comparisons between different rows of it:

```
SELECT a.id,
       COUNT(b.id)
FROM   <table> AS a
JOIN   <table> AS b
  ON   ST_Within(b.geom, a.geom)
 AND   a.id <> b.id
GROUP BY
       a.id
;
```